# On Geometric Brownian motion and Itô's formula

Tags: stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, geometric-brownian

Let $S_t$ be a geometric brownian motion such as 
$$d S(t) = rS(t)dt +\sigma S(t)dW(t),$$
where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion.

With Itô's lemma and formulas $(dt)^2=dtdW_t=dW_tdt=0$ and $(dW_t)^2=dt$, we can show that

$$
(dS_t)^2=\sigma^2 S_t^2 dt
$$
Problem:

At the beginning of a demonstration, the author of an article uses the following equality:
$$
(\int^T_0 dS_t)^2=\int^T_0 (dS_t)^2
$$
I can't see how he got such a result knowing that I find with Itô's lemma that :
$$
(\int^T_0 dS_t)^2=\int^T_0 (dS_t)^2+2(S_0^2-S_0S_T+\int^T_0 S_tdS_t)
$$
Help me see a little more clearly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is Ito isometry. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itô_isometry. I think you are missing the expectation operations.

Comment: Exactly, I think the author forgot to put the average operator.

Comment: This is an example of a convenient abuse of notation being used too far. Expressions such as $(\mathrm{d}W_t)^2=\mathrm{d}t$ are convenient for getting intuition and decluttering calculations, but mathematically they are a relaxation of rigourous notation. Hence it is no surprise that this over-simplified recasting can only be taken so far before it causes more harm than good and a misinterpretation and misuse. To correctly know what is going on under the hood (which you must do before you use this notation) you need to read up on quadratic variation and bracket processes. (cf. Klebaner)